# I have GIF sharing app but when I share on whatsapp it says "file format is not supported"

Tags: android

I have an image sharing app GIF and JPEG but whatsapp image sharing is not working, when i share it says "File format is not supported".

I have images in "Assets folder".

Please help ?

Comment: I'd guess that whatsapp does not support the GIF format ...

Comment: are you able to share the GIF to an E-Mail? to make sure the problem is only with whatsapp and not the file sharing all together.
please add the code for the intent, and if you are using the FileProvider, add this too.

Comment: you should add your code otherwise no one can help you